# HTML Encoding characters not in the character set

Tags: .net, c++, html, encoding, character-encoding

We have a web app which uses the ISO-8859-1 character set. Occationaly users have 'strange' names which contain characters like Š (html encoded here for your convenience). <del>We store this in our database, but</del> we can't display it correctly.

What is the best way of dealing with this? I'm thinking I should automatically convert characters outside the character set with its HTML Entity number encoding ( Š to `&#352;`)

But I'm having problems finding out how to do this automatically (without using a table of all values).

This code works for extended ASCII characters like 'å' (that are present in ISO-8859-1). I would like to do the same with other characters. Is there a pattern in these HTML entity encoding values I can use?

```
unsigned int c;  
for( int i=0; i < html.GetLength(); i++)  
{  
    c = html[i];  
    if( c > 255 || c < 0 )  
    {  
        CString orig = CString(html[i]);  
        CString encoded = "&#";  
        encoded += CTool::String((byte)c);  
        encoded += ";";  
        html.Replace(orig, encoded);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The webpage should instruct the browser to *display* the response in UTF-8. This usually happens by supplying the charset in the `Content-Type` response header like `text/html;charset=UTF-8`.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

The HTML/XML entities are solely there so that you will be able to *save* the webpage source in an encoding other than UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, this works, but I believe we are running ISO-8859-1 for a reason. Hopefully not, though... I'm going to check with the people who should know. It's a risky operation changing character set on all our servers, though I'd like that instead of coding an uneccesary workaround.

Comment: It's not risky as long as you was already using HTML entities for "special characters" outside the 7bit ASCII range. ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 namely have exactly the same byte representation of ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

html appears to be a "Unicode" CString. That means it's UTF-16 encoded. The "&#ddd" syntax uses the Unicode code point number. Usually, this is quite simple. `Š` is U+0160, which means it's 0x0160 in UTF-16. Tha's of course 352 decimal, so you get `&#352`.

You only have a problem when you encounter a character outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), which is past U+FFFF. This no longer fits in 16 bits, and will therefore take TWO characters in your `html` string. Yet, it should produce only one `&#ddddd` value. This is so rare that you often can ignore it.